# C# Libraries to encrypt/decrypt using AES

Tags: c#, security, encryption, aes

I couldn't find aes libraries in .net framework.
Is there any external libraries?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not mention which version of the framework you are using, but since you did not immediately find [`System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx), I guess you are using a version earlier than 3.5.

Instead use [`System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged(v=VS.100).aspx). Rijndael is the name of the algorithm that was standardized by NIST as AES. It is *exactly* the same algorithm (except that you can choose some blocklengths and modes with Rijndael that are not permitted with AES).

Comment: Actualy, i was reading the 2.0 documentation... :/ Thanks. And do you know if this algoritm is compatible with some Java implementation? I.e. i encrypt some text in C# and want to decrypt that text in java.

Comment: @nabo: Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");

Answer (score 6):

You'll find AES built into the framework in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx